# Using AWS Certificate Manager (ACM Certificate) with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-certificate-manager

When you have a certificate for your domain issued through AWS Certificate Manager, how do you apply that certificate to an Elastic Beanstalk application.

Yes, the Elastic Beanstalk application is load balanced and does have an ELB associated with it.

I know I can apply it directly to the ELB my self. But I want to apply it through Elastic Beanstalk so the env configuration is saved onto the Cloud Formation template.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found out, you cannot do it through the elastic beanstalk console (at least not yet). However you can still set it via the eb cli, or aws cli.

## Using EB CLI

Basically what we are trying to do is to update the `aws:elb:listener` setting, you can see the possible settings in the [general options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elblistener) docs.

Using the EB CLI is pretty simple. Assuming we already setup the `awsebcli` tool for our project we can use the `eb config` command.

It will open up your default terminal editor and allow you to change settings which are written as a YAML file. When you make a change and save it, the `eb config` cmd will automatically update the settings for your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

You will need to add the following settings to your config file:

```
aws:elb:listener:443:
  InstancePort: '80'
  InstanceProtocol: HTTP
  ListenerEnabled: 'true'
  ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
  PolicyNames: null
  SSLCertificateId: CERTIFICATE_ARN_HERE
```

Change the value for `CERTIFICATE_ARN_HERE` to your AMC Certificates ARN. You can find it in the AWS Certificate Manager console:

[image]

**IMPORTANT:** Your `aws:elb:listener:443` setting **MUST** be placed above the `aws:elb:listener:80` setting. Otherwise the environment configuration update will error out.

---

## Using AWS CLI

The same can be accomplished using the general `aws cli` tools via the [update-environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html) command.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
--environment-name APPLICATION_ENV --option-settings \
Namespace=aws:elb:listener:443,OptionName=InstancePort,Value=80 \
Namespace=aws:elb:listener:443,OptionName=InstanceProtocol,Value=HTTP \
Namespace=aws:elb:listener:443,OptionName=ListenerProtocol,Value=HTTPS \
Namespace=aws:elb:listener:443,OptionName=SSLCertificateId,Value=CERTIFICATE_ARN_HERE
```

**NOTE:** When you update it via either of the methods above, the Elastic Beanstalk console will not show HTTPS as enabled. But the load balancer will, and it will also apply to the Cloudformation template as well get saved into the EB's configuration.

Comment: I have try it by eb cli and by adding config file under .ebextensions it always says "Server Certificate not found for the key...."

http://egscr.com/JpcAa8

Comment: @Max you do not add the config file in the .ebextensions folder. The eb cli will download the config file and re-upload it back to elastic beanstalk when you create a change. IT is not the same as adding an ebextension.

Comment: @KirillFuchs With the AWS CLI option, is it the same syntax for ec2?

Comment: @Jeboy no, the command to add it directly to a load balancer would be different.

Comment: @KirillFuchs Ok, I was trying that route as I was having problem with certificate from ACM being invalid. I setup AWS classic load balancer with HTTPS Listener using ACM certificate as described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html but the browser rejects it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929255/aws-acm-certificate-not-valid

Comment: This is great with ebcli `eb config`  but regarding your note: "MUST be placed above the `aws:elb:listener:80` setting"   --what if we don't have that setting in the existing config, does that need to be set?

Comment: @Jordan if the update didn't error out then you're all good :). But I should note that you can now add an ACM certificate to elastic beanstalk through the console.

Answer (score 2):

I find the simplest way is change the EB Load Balancer via the user console. Click change and select the new ACM certificate.
[image]

When you view the EB configuration, it will not appear, but it will be set

Answer (score 0):

You can do this purely with CloudFormation; however, as seems to be quite common with Elastic Beanstalk the configuration options are much harder to find in the docs than they are for the individual components that comprise Elastic Beanstalk. The info is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbloadbalancer

But basically what you need to do is add the creation of the cert to your template and then reference it in `OptionSettings` in `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate`:

```
"Certificate" : {
      "Type": "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
      "Properties": {
        "DomainName": "example.com",
      }
    },
// ...
"ElasticbeanstalkTemplate": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate",
      "Properties": {
        "SolutionStackName": "MyEBStack",
        "ApplicationName": "MyAppName",
        "Description": "",
        "OptionSettings": [{
          "Namespace": "aws:elb:listener:443",
          "OptionName": "InstancePort",
          "Value": "80"
        }, {
          "Namespace": "aws:elb:listener:443",
          "OptionName": "InstanceProtocol",
          "Value": "HTTP"
        }, {
          "Namespace": "aws:elb:listener:443",
          "OptionName": "ListenerProtocol",
          "Value": "HTTPS"
        }, {
          "Namespace": "aws:elb:listener:443",
          "OptionName": "SSLCertificateId",
          "Value": {
            "Ref": "Certificate"
          }
        }, /*More settings*/]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in which zone you created the certificate and if it matches the Elastic Beanstalk zone. I had them in different zones so it didn't work.