# Adding SSL to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My AWS certificate is not showing as an option in the **SSL certificate ID** dropdown.  I believe that this is required to force the Elastic Beanstalk to use HTTPS.  I am using an AWS issued cert.  Here are the steps from the manual that I am following.

```
To assign a certificate to your environment's loadbalancer
  1) Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
  2) Navigate to the management console for your environment.
  3) Choose Configuration.
  4) In the Network Tier section, choose the gear icon next to Load Balancing.
  5) In the Load Balancer section, choose your certificate from the SSL certificate ID drop down menu.
```

Comment: Someone else found the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35173500/329062

Answer (score 2):

My problem was I trying to use the cert i commissioned through AWS (they allow you to do this) through their cert manager, I was trying to use that on my EC2 instance.  I'm not sure that Amazon is aware of this but the AWS granted cert is NOT available in the dropdown list in your Elastic beanstalk instance networking configuration load-balancer option (but it is available when you edit the EC2 load balancer).  As it turns out ... you must create and upload your own cert to make both options work.

- STEP 1: EC2 Dashboard

  1. Goto Load Balancers
  2. Goto Listeners Tab
  3. Press Edit
  4. Press Add
  5. Enter
  6. LoadBalancer Protocal = HTTPS
  7. Load Balancer Port = 443
  8. (leave Instance Protocol default)
  9. Press Change on SSL Cert
  10. Add your Private & Public Key
  11. Press Save

NEXT...

- STEP 2: Elastic Beanstalk Dashboard

  1. Goto your Beanstalk instance
  2. Goto Configuration
  3. Goto Load Balancing (under Network Tier)
  4. On Secure listener port, set Protocol to "HTTPS"
  5. On SSL certificate ID Dropdown to your cert

Comment: "I was trying to use that on my EC2 instance" ... should read "I was trying to use that on my elastic beanstalk instance"

Comment: They don't automatically show up in the dropdown list where you typically choose your cert.

Answer (score 1):

As of May 23rd, AWS has added support for using certs obtained from the AWS Cert Manager in your Elastic Beanstalk.  Below is the press release from their May 31st AWS Announcements:

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk Supports AWS Certificate Manager Posted On: May
>   23, 2016
>
> You can now use SSL/TLS certificates provisioned from AWS Certificate
>   Manager with your AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments by selecting a
>   certificate from the Elastic Beanstalk console. This helps you easily
>   secure network communications between your Elastic Beanstalk
>   applications and end users.
>
> AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) is a service that lets you easily
>   provision, manage, and deploy Secure Sockets Layer/Transport Layer
>   Security (SSL/TLS) certificates for use with AWS services. SSL/TLS
>   certificates provisioned through AWS Certificate Manager are free. You
>   pay only for the AWS resources you create to run your application.
>
> You can start choosing ACM certificates for your Elastic Beanstalk
>   applications from the Elastic Beanstalk console or with the EB CLI,
>   SDKs, and APIs. Read our documentation to learn more. You must
>   provision a certificate from ACM before you can use it with Elastic
>   Beanstalk. To get started with ACM, visit [here](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/).

Answer (score 0):

Because you created the certificate in a different zone than the Load balancer, as per Amazon docs, the certificate and elb have to be in the **same zone.**