# Creating load balancer failed Reason: Server Certificate not found for the key

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am facing a a weird issue trying to rebuild a Elastic Beanstalk Environment. The error is:

```
Creating load balancer failed Reason: Server Certificate not found for the key: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:************:certificate/f0fc94b2-9c9b-423c-8e00-4a6eef316473 (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: CertificateNotFound; Request ID: e0c2604a-5b56-4eb0-be72-9275fedce0cf; Proxy: null)
```

I tried to follow the steps at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098858/aws-certificate-manager-acm-certificate-with-elastic-beanstalk)  but I'm getting this error while trying to change the configuration

```
Environment named env-name is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.
```

I was wondering if there's a way to relocate a certificate for that key or change the key it's trying to find?

Comment: Did you check your Elastic Beanstalk Environment region with ACM region? 
It should be on same region. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102044/5589820