# AWS ACM Certificate Not Valid

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-certificate-manager

I setup AWS classic load balancer with HTTPS Listener using ACM certificate as described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html but the browser rejects it.

Errors:

- This root certificate is not trusted (ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
- The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.
- The certificate is only valid for the following names: localhost,
  localhost.localdomain, ip-10-0-0-157,
  ip-10-0-0-157.us-west-2.compute.internal
- (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

The generated certificate seems pointed to localhost.

Comment: That definitely should not be the case.  Can we have the DNS hostname of the balancer in question?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot nuc-load-balancer-1532220844.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com

uses an invalid security certificate.

Comment: Note: I updated the error messages in the description

Comment: did you find out what the problem was?  Having similar issue