# Adding SSL Cert to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I had a working friendly name pointed to my elastic beanstalk site. I wanted to add an SSL cert and now it will not route. Not sure what broke, but here is what I've tried:

1) Went inton EB console and changed scaling to support load balancing. (OK)

2) Got an ssl cert  from AWS certificate manager (OK)

3) Went back to console/LoadBalancing and selected my SSL certificate from the
    drop down menu. Hit apply and waited for the healthcheck to turn
    green. It did, but I could no longer access my domain from HTTP or
    HTTPS. The only way to browse to it was through the environment URL.
    When I went back to console/LoadBalancing I saw that it had not
    changed. I tried again and same issue, no way to browse and the SSL
    cert doesn't stick.

4) I created an
    .ebextensions/securelistenerconfig file as specified here:
    [AWS doc: Configuring Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Load Balancer to Terminate HTTPS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html) 
    I ran eb depoly and saw it loaded OK. However, still no browsing or
    changes in the console.

5) I checked this [stackoverflow message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172506/using-aws-certificate-manager-acm-certificate-with-elastic-beanstalk/35173500#35173500)
    and confirmed my config file was correct (it had an elb:listener:443
    with my certificate arn name and it was above the :80 listener)

6)
    I went to route53 and deleted my existing hosted zone (it had the old elastic IP address which got deleted when I added the laod balancer)and replaced
    it with a new one that has the A record pointing (as an alias) to my load
    balancer per these instructions [Configure a Custom Domain Name for your Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html?icmpid=docs_elb_console)

Nothing I've tried has worked so would appreciate any additional things to try.

Comment: *"went to route53 and deleted my existing hosted zone"*  Well, there's the problem.  Don't do that.  You can't put a hosted zone back in an identical state if you delete it.  You have to make some additional changes external to the hosted zone.  Assuming your domain is also registered with Route 53, you'll find the solution for this issue at the question of which this question is now marked as a duplicate.

Comment: If I have misdiagnosed this issue, you can edit your question to add further information, and the community can vote to reopen it.

Comment: YES! That solved the not routing issue...but still the SSL cert is not "sticking" to the domain name. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: What does not "sticking" mean, @edswartz?

Comment: Not sticking = the site can not be reached when browsing to HTTPS ... but now it can. Time to get out of chair and walk around the block. Thank you for your help.